# Can Java MethodHandles be considered the same as first class functions?

Tags: java, java-7, higher-order-functions

Java [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) Class and Java 7's [MethodHandle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) Class both refer to objects that are associated to methods, but still they are rarely used and when a function needs to be passed to another, it is preferred to use an anonymous class that implements an interface that contains one method.

*(Note: MethodHandles are supposed to be faster than the old Methods.)*

Why aren't these constructs used more often to pass functions to functions? Is it because they are still verbose?

Code example:

```
public final class HigherOrder {

public static final List<?> map(final List<?> list, final MethodHandle mh) throws Throwable {
    if (list == null) return null;
    List<Object> ret = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (Object element : list) {
        ret.add(mh.invoke(element));
    }
    return ret;
}

public static final Object reduce(final List<?> list, final MethodHandle mh) throws Throwable {
    if (list == null) return null;
    Object tmp = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        tmp = mh.invoke(tmp, list.get(i));
    }
    return tmp;
}

public static final Integer doubleNumber(final Integer number) {
    return number * 2;
}

public static final Integer sum(final Integer number1, final Integer number2) {
    return number1 + number2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle doubleNumber = lookup.unreflect(HigherOrder.class.getMethod("doubleNumber", Integer.class));
    MethodHandle sum = lookup.findStatic(HigherOrder.class, "sum", MethodType.methodType(Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class));

    List<?> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    System.out.println(list);
    list = map(list, doubleNumber);
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(reduce(list, sum));
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

After doing some benchmarking, I noticed that MethodHandle is faster than Reflection's method, but still nowhere near as fast as a regular method call. Maybe for the method call the JVM can apply some optimizations that are not possible with the handles.

Comment: Aren't they rather slow?

Comment: I have to say I haven't done any benchmarking yet.

Comment: Methods are rarely used cause they use reflection and are significantly slower than a direct method call.  MethodHandles are rarely used cause they didn't exist until very recently.  (Java7)

Comment: Method handles are **not** faster than native invocation or reflection. The API is mainly intended for linking invokedynamic call sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from any performance arguments, passing around Methods or MethodHandles:

- loses any compile-time safety:

  - number of arguments;
  - types of arguments;
  - the existence of the method itself (you use a string name to find it).
- loses any declared checked exceptions;
- makes automated refactoring more difficult.

Also, as your code demonstrates, using Methods or MethodHandles doesn't particularly cut down on the amount of code required to declare an object approximating a first-class function:

```
// you could even use the Function types from Guava...
interface Func<In, Out> {
    Out apply(In in);
}

// create a new "function" object in 5 lines of code:
Func<String, Integer> parseInt = new Func<String, Integer> {
    public Integer apply(String in) {
        return Integer.parseInt(in);
    }
}
```

Admittedly it's not as nice as a real lambda syntax, but the type-safety, refactoring benefits and ease of explanation make typing out those five lines the least-worst option much of the time.

Comment: Well, Guava remains type-safety but they still are anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

Only use reflection when you really need to. 
As you can see invoke throws Throwable which means you get no real good exception handling.
Also other compile time checks will be discarded.

Comment: Loss of exception handling is a deal. Although it seems that lots of Java people don't like checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

[Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) class has its place when one needs to use reflection, which is much slower than regular method call.

[MethodHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) is part of [JSR 292](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=292). It targets people who implement dynamic languages for JVM. You can read more about it [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/DynTypeLang/). It doesn't mean to replace regular method call either.

Comment: Yeah, it is slow still. I guess when Groovy implements it, it will be faster but not as fast as Java. As a matter of fact Groovy is moving to a static type system.

Answer (score 0):

MethodHandles use reflection, so they're slow and not easily refactorable. Moreover, Java will get lambdas in it version 8 and this will solve the problem of first class functions in Java, so I suppose library writers prefer waiting for Java 8 than using some kind of workaround.

Comment: Yes they are still slow sadly. I wonder how they'll solve the performance penalty with lambdas.

Comment: The CICE lambdas proposal is a mere syntactic shortcut for anonymous inner classes, so it will be as fast as building a simple object and calling a method. You can't get any much faster... The other proposals are conceptually more complex, but should be statically typed and more or less equivalent in terms of VM plumbing. So I guess Java lambdas will be order of magnitudes faster than reflection-based mechanisms.